# JxBrowser - 5.4 - rendering select><option ...> ... </select> out of page

Tags: jxbrowser

I have a JxBrowser panel embedded in a swing panel. 
It happens that   is rendered out  of the panel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svk7D.png)

Answer (score 0):

To display drop down menu, JxBrowser 5.x uses pure Swing API. If you see this issue with drop down menu size, then it means that the issue is in Java Swing. Maybe this issue is already solved in latest JRE versions. You can try running your app with latest JRE and see whether behavior is improved or not.